# AdStock Transformation in R

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics, exp, data-transform

I am referencing this document here: 
https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/7683/4/Adstock

On Page 6 there is a formula for AdStock Transformation that looks like this: 
[image]

I found an R code that reproduces this adstock transformation below:
https://analyticsartist.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/calculating-adstock-effect/

[image]

R-Code:

```
adstock_rate = 0.50
advertising = c(117.913, 120.112, 125.828, 115.354, 177.090, 141.647, 137.892,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 
            0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 158.511, 109.385,  91.084,  79.253, 102.706, 
            78.494, 135.114, 114.549,  87.337, 107.829, 125.020,  82.956,  60.813,  83.149,   0.000,   0.000, 
            0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 129.515, 105.486, 111.494, 107.099,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 
            0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000)

adstocked_advertising = numeric(length(advertising))
adstocked_advertising[1] = advertising[1]
for(i in 2:length(advertising)){
  adstocked_advertising[i] = advertising[i] + adstock_rate * 
adstocked_advertising[i-1]
}
```

Plot:

[image]

When I attempted to use the formula on page 6, my output looked way different and did not seem accurate. Does anyone know how to reproduce the first formula rather than the last?

Here was my attempt:

```
adstocked_advertising = numeric(length(advertising))
adstocked_advertising[1] = advertising[1]
for(i in 2:length(advertising)){
 adstocked_advertising[i] = 1/(1+exp(-v*advertising[i])) + 
adstock_rate*adstocked_advertising[i-1]}
```

Output plot: 
[image]

Comment: Your attempt looks fine. Do you think it's wrong?

Comment: The graph looks very strange, I'll add the output. It's just a consistent downcurve and it doesn't really fluctuate when there are new numbers in the list after a series of 0's.

Comment: just added the plot.

Comment: What value are you using for the "v" parameter?

Comment: my value is 0.6

Comment: @Luis does this seem like a normal output for you? I am very new to adstock and assumed it would fluctuate alittle bit based on the new numbers coming in after 0.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the math. I'm not familiar with adstock, but you're not doing anything wrong, so maybe that's just a feature of that specific model

Comment: Note that no matter what value you choose for "v", the expression 1/(1+exp(-v*advertising[i])) will be a number between 0 and 1, so it's no wonder your graph doesn't change much in the parts where the advertising variable surges

Comment: That's really weird because it was one of the options for formulas to use. Will look further into it. Thanks!